# The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, xcode7

MACPCHD95PC:homepage-hackdays-ios-master BBC$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Cloning spec repo `bbc` from `git@github.com:bbc/map-ios-podspecs.git`
**[!] Unable to add a source with url `git@github.com:bbc/map-ios-podspecs.git` named `bbc`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.**
MACPCHD95PC:homepage-hackdays-ios-master BBC$

I am getting this error on trying to solve the below mentioned issue.

**diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.**

How do the solve this ??

Comment: You should try to remove Podfile.lock file and Pods folder, then run pod install again

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove `Podfile.lock`, and do another `pod install`.